# How to ad the attribute aria-expanded=true/false to an element

Tags: javascript, wai-aria

On my site, I have an accordion with the following structure
(generated by ckeditor-accordion)

```
<dl>
  <dt>title 1</dt>
 <dd>content 1</dd>
 <dt class="active">title 2</dt>
 <dd>content 2</dd>
</dl>
```

It should have the result that when the `dt-element` has `class="active"` the attribute `"aria-expanded=true"` is added, else it should be `"aria-expanded=false"` by default.

I suppose it's something like

```
document.getElementByTagName("dt").setAttribute("aria-expanded", false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The element that **does** the expanding/collapsing is the one that should have `aria-expanded` set on it.  Make sure you **don't** set `aria-expanded` on the elements that are expanded.

So in your case, it looks like the `<dt>` should have `aria-expanded`.  And you're correct that the value should be `true` when the section is expanded and `false` when it's collapsed.  The `<dd>` is the container that holds the contents.  It should **not** have `aria-expanded`.

I know your code snippet was just a brief summary of your idea.  Hopefully your real code has more attributes set.  For example, the element that has `aria-expanded` should be a `<button>` and contained in a heading.  If you're using a definition list (`<dl>`) as your structure, you need `role="presentation"` on the `<dl>` so that a screen reader doesn't announce that there's a list.

The "[WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion)" has a good section on accordions.

To actually change the value of the `aria-expanded` attribute, you do the same thing you would for changing any other attribute via javascript.  Your suggestion of using `setAttribute()` is fine.